# How to use a looped list to generate proc sql tables

Tags: list, loops, sas

I'm trying to loop through a list and use each of the list values to create a new table.

I wrote a macro in order to do so.

```
%macro loop(STlist);
%let nwords=%sysfunc(countw(&STlist));

%do i=1 %to &nwords;

%put %scan(&STlist, &i);

%LET ST_CD = %scan(&STlist, &i);

%end;
%mend;

%loop(&STATE);
```

Here is my state list:

```
%LET STATE = AK AL AZ AR CA CO CT DC DE FL GA HI ID IL IN IA KS KY LA ME MD MA MI MN MS MO MT NE NV NH NJ NM NY NC ND OH OK OR PA RI SC SD TN TX UT VT VA WA WV WI WY;
```

I'm trying to create proc sql tables each time with each state abbreviation in the list.

Comment: If you want the macro to generate SQL code then it has to actually contain some SQL code.

Comment: Just insert your SQL Code after the second %let Statement and use &ST_CD. wherever you need to use the state code.

Comment: How does this post substantively differ from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57897322/1422451)? Please edit previous version with needed info rather than inundate StackOverflow with duplicate questions.

Answer (score 1):

For example your code could look like this, which would create 51 empty data sets named AK, AL and so on.

```
%macro loop(STlist);
  %let nwords=%sysfunc(countw("&STlist"));
  %put nwords=*&nwords.*;

  %do i=1 %to &nwords;
    %LET ST_CD = %scan(&STlist, &i);
    %put ST_CD=*&ST_CD.*;

    /* Create empty data set with one variable value1*/
    proc sql;
      create table &ST_CD.
      (value1 char 100);
    quit;
  %end;
%mend;
```